# Which manga chapter correspond to the end of episode 13 of season 2 of the anime?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

I don't know which chapter season 2 episode 13 ends.

I just started watching it. I tried but could not find it.

Which manga chapter correspond to the end of episode 13 of season 2 of the anime?

Answer (score 0):

The **Seven Deadly Sins: Revival of The Commandments** episode 13 covers chapters 138, 143, 144, 145 and 146 (source: [Wiki](http://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_of_The_Commandments_Episode_13)), so the end of episode 13 should be chapter 146.

In case you're asking because you want to continue reading the manga where the anime left off start from chapter 146.

By the way you can find a chapter to episode comparison broken down by arcs [here](http://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Story_Arcs).